# How to debug Perl that is called from PHP file

Tags: php, perl, debugging

I am currently working from home (on a Sunday!) and I am trying to figure out why my Perl script is returning NULL to PHP from where it is called. However, I don't see how I can debug the Perl script itself. The PHP file returns a warning that I am trying to do an array operation on a non-array object (because the expected array is actually NULL returned by PHP). The logs of the webserver have only logged this warning as well - no Perl errors.

Is there a place where specific 'external' logs are stored on a server? Or, is there a better way to debug a Perl file that is been run from a PHP file that is required in a main PHP file? Debugging isn't necessary (I don't need a *debug mode*) but I'd like to see the errors or warnings at least.

Comment: Can you change the source of the Perl script to add some debugging code?

Comment: @bart I can do that, indeed. What would I write?

Comment: Can you run the Perl program yourself without the php inbetween? Do you know what goes in and what is supposed to come out? Do you have shell access?

Comment: @simbabque No, I can only run the file from the PHP file, via the server. I do not have shell access. (Otherwise I would simply run the script from shell.)

Comment: So the debugger is not an option. The [answer by bart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826392/1331451) is a good start, but it's also important to know what the program is supposed to do. I take it you can't install any modules either since you don't have shell access. Combine @bart's solution with a bunch of `warn` statements, possibly using Data::Dumper, and you should be able to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following code at the top of your Perl script:

```
sub debug_log
{
    open my $log_fh, ">>", "/tmp/debug.log";
    print $log_fh $_[0];
    warn $_[0];
    close $log_fh;
}

$SIG{__WARN__} = \&debug_log;
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&debug_log;
```

This way all the warnings and `die` messages should end up in `/tmp/debug.log`.

Comment: Would that tmp directory be relative to the Perl file itself (so a sister of that script), to the PHP file, or to the main PHP file? Because on first glance I cannot find it.

Comment: The path specified as the `open` argument is absolute, so you should have a file in `/tmp`. If there is no file, then it means there were no warnings or the script did not die. You can test if the warnings are logged correctly, by using `warn "debug test";` right after the `$SIG...` lines.